# assignment error I can't make sense in new object expression

Tags: c#

When defining the Toggled1 class, I get a "assignment, call, increment, and new object expressions cannot be used statement" error. Is there a way to write the Toggled1 class in another way?

6 of the 7 errors in the photo are related to Toggle D1. Yellow warning sign is not an important case

https://i.stack.imgur.com/24SnS.jpg

Here is the code :

```
public partial class ToggleButton : UserControl
{
    Thickness Leftside = new Thickness(-39, 0, 0, 0);
    Thickness Rightside = new Thickness(0, 0, -39, 0);
    SolidColorBrush Off = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(160, 160, 160));
    SolidColorBrush On = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(130, 190, 125));
    private bool Toggled = false;
    public ToggleButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool Toggled1 { get => Toggled; set => Toggled = value; }

    private void Dot_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Toggled)
        {
            Back.Fill = On;
            Toggled = true;
            Dot.Margin = Rightside;
        }
        else
        {
            Back.Fill = Off;
            Toggled = false;
            Dot.Margin = Leftside;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `public bool Toggled1 { get => Toggled; set => Toggled = value; }` to `public bool Toggled { get; set; }` and remove `private bool Toggled = false;`.

Comment: thanks mjwills, these situations are overlooked when you type code for hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Change:

```
public bool Toggled1 { get => Toggled; set => Toggled = value; }
```

to

```
public bool Toggled1 { get { return Toggled }; set { Toggled = value;} }
```

**Option 2:**
Make `Toggled`  it as a public property:

```
public bool Toggled {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggled1 looks to be a property, not a class.  Further, it's the only use of your private Toggled value I see which makes it a good candidate for an [auto-property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties).  I believe what you're looking for is this:

```
public bool Toggled { get; set; }
```